# Rotate marker based on driving direction

Tags: android, google-maps, angle, direction, driving-directions

I have a marker in my Google Maps map that looks like this:

[image: pic]

When the user is driving, I want to rotate it based on his driving direction. How can I achieve this? I should probably use previous location and current location coords for calculation, but I have no idea how.

Comment: You obviously know how to find the position. Before the first loop set the previous pos same as current. Then your loop continually calculates the distance between the previous and the current positions and when it is large enough to matter, the direction with something like `atan2(dy,dx)` at which point you set the marker orientation, then remember `previous == current` and do another loop.

Comment: Why don't you use `bearing` of the `Location` object? You can set it to the `CameraPosition`.

Comment: how do I do it in the leaflet api?

Answer (score 40):

If you use GPS for locating the user then the `Location` object you get in `onLocationChanged` contains the [bearing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()).

If you only have the two coordinates (e.g. you only have coordinates from network location provider), you can use `Location.bearingTo()` to calculate the bearing of two coordinates:

```
Location prevLoc = ... ;
Location newLoc = ... ;
float bearing = prevLoc.bearingTo(newLoc) ;
```

If you have a bearing, you can set the rotation of the marker using [`MarkerOptions.rotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#rotation(float)):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(markerLatLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker))
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .rotation(bearing)
                    .flat(true));
```

You have to set the [anchor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)) to the point you want to rotate around, and it's also the point you want to be at the position you set to the marker. (0.5, 0.5) is the center of the image.

Comment: Based on this answer how does it know the front and the side of the car?

Comment: It doesn't know, it assumes that the car moves forward (it uses two sequential positions, the direction of the movement points to the latter one).

Comment: Any idea how to do this on Angular Google Maps?