# how to rotate marker(bus) according to direction?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

From Below Code I am adding marker on map and every 15 seconds its refreshing and getting new latitude and longitude from database. Marker(Bus Image) are successfully adding on map and moving smoothly from one position to another position like car goes on road. Now what I want that I want to rotate bus marker according to direction. How can I achieve this? I am not getting what is the value of toRotation and st ?

```
public Runnable runLocation = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MapActivity.this);
            MyLocation1.clear();
            if (gps.CanGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                if (circle != null) {
                    circle.remove();
                }
                if (busMarker != null){
                    lastBusPos = busMarker.getPosition();
                }

                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location))
                        .title("My Location")
                        .position(mylocation));

                circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                        .center(mylocation)
                        .radius(1000)
                        .strokeColor(0x10000000)
                        .fillColor(0x10000000));
            } else {
                // gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

            String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
            String url = AppConfig.RouteData + "i=1&" + "y=1";

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                        JSONArray json_user = jObj.getJSONArray("Message");
                        for (int i = 0; i < json_user.length(); i++) {

                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = json_user.getJSONObject(i);

                                final Double currLat = obj.getDouble("actual_lat");
                                final Double currLong = obj.getDouble("actual_long");
                                final LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(currLat, currLong);


                                List<LatLng> latList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                                latList.add(hcmus);

                                if (mMarkers.size() != json_user.length()) {
                                    busMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus))
                                            .title("Bus No" + obj.getString("bus_id"))
                                            .position(hcmus));
                                    mMarkers.add(busMarker);
                                } else {
                                    //busMarker.setPosition(hcmus);
                                    animateMarker(hcmus, false);
                                    rotateMarker(busMarker, 45.0f, 45.0f);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Sorry something went wrong..Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

            MapActivity.this.handler.postDelayed(MapActivity.this.runLocation, 15000);
        }

    };

    /*-------------------------------Animation----------------------------*/
    public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation, final float st) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = st;
        final long duration = 1555;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                float rot = t * toRotation + (1 - t) * startRotation;

                marker.setRotation(-rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot);
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void animateMarker(final LatLng toPosition,final boolean hideMarke) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(lastBusPos);
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 5000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                busMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarke) {
                        busMarker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        busMarker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may refer with this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092113/rotate-marker-based-on-driving-direction). Use [bearing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()) of the `Location` object then set it to the `CameraPosition`.

> If you use GPS for locating the user then the `Location` object you
>   get in `onLocationChanged` contains the [bearing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()).
>
> If you only have the two coordinates (e.g. you only have coordinates
>   from network location provider), you can use `Location.bearingTo()` to
>   calculate the bearing of two coordinates:
>
> ```
> Location prevLoc = ... ;
> Location newLoc = ... ;
> float bearing = prevLoc.bearingTo(newLoc) ;
> ```
>
> If you have a bearing, you can set the rotation of the marker using
>   [`MarkerOptions.rotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#rotation(float)):
>
> ```
> mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>                     .position(markerLatLng)
>                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker))
>                     .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
>                     .rotation(bearing)
>                     .flat(true));
> ```
>
> You have to set the [anchor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)) to the point you want to rotate
>   around, and it's also the point you want to be at the position you set
>   to the marker. (0.5, 0.5) is the center of the image.

Here are some posts which might also help:

- [Change Google map marker orientation according path direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149613/change-google-map-marker-orientation-according-path-direction)
- [Rotate marker as per user direction on Google Maps V2 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704834/rotate-marker-as-per-user-direction-on-google-maps-v2-android)

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code.**
It's very easy to implement.

Here latLng1=old your location & latLng2=your new location.

**Step=1**

```
 private double getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {

        double lat1 = degreesToRadians(latLng1.latitude);
        double long1 = degreesToRadians(latLng1.longitude);
        double lat2 = degreesToRadians(latLng2.latitude);
        double long2 = degreesToRadians(latLng2.longitude);


        double dLon = (long2 - long1);


        double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
                * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

        double radiansBearing = Math.atan2(y, x);


        return radiansToDegrees(radiansBearing);
    }
```

**Step=2**

```
private double degreesToRadians(double degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    }
```

**Step=3**

```
private double radiansToDegrees(double radians) {
    return radians * 180.0 / Math.PI;
}
```

**Step=4** Set your marker rotation.

```
 mPositionMarker.setRotation((float) getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(new LatLng(lastLocLati, lastLocLongi), new LatLng(lati, longi)));
```

Comment: Your code work perfect to change direction but i need to change the position at the same time. When i set position after this .setRotation line, Marker move and change direction successfully but when it reach at 2nd point it again change its direction to original direction of icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to move and rotate marker at same time with use of bearing -

```
   public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition, final boolean hideMarker) {
    boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(toPosition);

    if(!contains){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toPosition, 60));
     // MOVE CAMERA
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 500;
    final float toRotation = (float) bearingBetweenLocations(marker.getPosition(), toPosition);
    final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            //rotate marker
            float rot = t * toRotation + (1 - t) * startRotation;
            float bearing = -rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot;
            marker.setRotation(bearing);
            //move marker
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.latitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


private double bearingBetweenLocations(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {
    double PI = 3.14159;
    double lat1 = latLng1.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long1 = latLng1.longitude * PI / 180;
    double lat2 = latLng2.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long2 = latLng2.longitude * PI / 180;
    double dLon = (long2 - long1);
    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;
    return brng;
}
```